Send & receive message in same workflow
I have a Lambda function that performs QLDB transactions. Because QLDB uses OCC (optimistic concurrency control), it's necessary to add a SQS Fifo in front, making sure that potential conflicting transactions (in my case: transactions attached to a specific user) are processed in sequence.
Using the SQS SendMessage.waitForTaskToken can solve this problem, but it requires the use of multiple workflows.
Is it possible to add to a SQS and wait for the just-added message to be emitted from the SQS? I'm trying to avoid splitting this step function up.

Based on my knowledge, instead of splitting the step function, you can create a solution that sends messages to the SQS FIFO queue and processes them sequentially using a Lambda function. The Lambda function can ensure that transactions attached to a specific user are processed one at a time.
Let's see some ways you can go about this:

Create SQS FIFO Queue
Send a message to SQS FIFO Queue
Trigger the Lamda function
Sequentially process the messages.



#SendMessage to SQS FIFO:

import boto3
import json

sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
queue_url = 'https://sqs.<region>.amazonaws.com/<account-id>/<queue-name>.fifo'

def send_message(user_id, transaction_data):
    response = sqs.send_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        MessageBody=json.dumps(transaction_data),
        MessageGroupId=str(user_id),
        MessageDeduplicationId=str(user_id) + "-" + str(transaction_data['transaction_id'])
    )
    return response


#Lambda Function to Process SQS Messages:
import boto3
import json
from qldb_helpers import process_transaction  # Your QLDB transaction logic

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        message_body = json.loads(record['body'])
        user_id = record['messageAttributes']['MessageGroupId']['stringValue']
        
        # Process the QLDB transaction
        process_transaction(user_id, message_body)
        
        # Delete the message after successful processing
        sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
        sqs.delete_message(
            QueueUrl=record['eventSourceARN'],
            ReceiptHandle=record['receiptHandle']
        )



